# Creating A GUI for Editing A Config File Using Python

Tags: python, user-interface

So, I have **a .toml config** file and its something like this:

```
[APU]
apu = "any"                                         # Audio system. Use: [any, nop, sdl, xaudio2]
[CPU]
break_condition_gpr = -1                            # GPR compared to
break_condition_op = "eq"                           # comparison operator
```

I know how to pars the toml file (using it's module)

I want to make a program using python, that let's other users choose for example the apu mentioned above (between **any,nop,sdl,...)**,meaning the program suggests the options **(any,nop,sdl...)** and the user can choose whatever option they want.

the problem is that I don't know where to start!(not coding wise, I don't even know that if there is a module that would help me or even other things mayby? (I'm Confused and don't know where to search for a tutorial)
I have no idea what to do next.

Comment: This question is not in line with SO guidelines. It needs more focus and/or is borderline request for recommendation of off-site resources. Check [help/on-topic].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tkinter is python's standard GUI framework however lacks a lot of features and is really only useful for the most basic of GUI's.

If you're looking for something a bit more powerful I would suggest having a look at [Kivy](https://kivy.org/#home), it's open-source and has good documentation, it is primarily intended for mobile development but is perfectly well suited for desktop apps too.

Answer (score 0):

You can use TKinter to create a simple GUI for the app. The documentation is very descriptive and you can find many resources on how to get started easily since it is part of the python standard library.